# How to count number per month and then take average of it in same select statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, average

**How to calculate total average per month in case like below?:**

We have 9 claimID's. so Aveage would be 9/ 6 distinct months = 1.5

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (claimid int, DateClosed datetime)

INSERT INTO @TestTable  
VALUES (111, '01-01-2018'), (222, '01-03-2018'), (333, '01-12-2018'),
       (444, '07-03-2018'), (555, '08-15-2018'), (666, '09-13-2018'),
       (777, '04-03-2019'), (888, '05-01-2019'), (999, '07-01-2018'),
       (1000, NULL), (1100, NULL), (1200, NULL)

SELECT 
    ClaimID,
    CAST(DateClosed AS DATE) AS DateClosed,
    COUNT(ClaimID) CountClaimID,
    COUNT(claimid) OVER (PARTITION BY MONT(DateClosed), YEAR(DateClosed)) AS CountPerMonth
FROM 
    @TestTable
GROUP BY 
    ClaimID, DateClosed
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: 1.5 is the average of what?

Comment: average count of ClaimID per Year-Month. So total we have 9 claimId / 6 distinct month = 1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

**Example**

```
SELECT ClaimID
       ,cast(DateClosed AS date) AS DateClosed
       ,count(ClaimID) CountClaimID
       ,count(claimid) OVER ( PARTITION BY Month(DateClosed), year(DateClosed)) AS CountPerMonth
       ,case when DateClosed is null then 0 else count(DateClosed) over () / (select 0.0+count(distinct left(cast(DateClosed as date),7)) from @TestTable) end AS TotalAverage
FROM   @TestTable
GROUP  BY ClaimID,DateClosed
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: John, its amazing! The only thing in my real query I have `NULL`'s as `DateClosed` sometimes.  Is there any way to `count(ClaimID)` that only have `DateClosed`?

Comment: @Oleg Updated for NULLs.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh! you counted `DateClosed` instead! Cause I tried case statement but I still counted `ClaimID`'s.    Thank you